# Exception:Grails tag [g:applyLayout] was not closed

Tags: grails, gsp

I have no clue why this happens.I have a template named _showcontacts.gsp.The source is as follows:

```
 <content tag="column1"> 
 <div class="form-edit">
    <div class="heading">
        <strong>
            <g:message code="Contact Details of the firm:"/>${name}
        </strong>
    </div>

     <div id="hai" class="form-hold">
        <form name="company-edit-form" action="save">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-columns">


                    <div class="column" >
                          <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Company Name"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Company</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Company"  id="Company"  />
                        </g:applyLayout>
                          <content> 
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="First Name"/>

                             <textField class="field" name="firstName"  id="Company">
                              <label for="txt1"></label>
                              <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" value="${contact.firstName}">
                            </textField>
                            <br>

                            <g:message code="Group"/>

                             <textField class="field" name="group"  id="Company">
                              <label for="txt2"></label>
                              <input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" value="${contact.group}">
                            </textField>

                            <br>

                            <g:message code="ID"/>

                             <textField class="field" name="id"  id="Company">
                              <label for="txt3"></label>
                              <input type="text" name="txt3" id="txt3" value="${contact.id}">
                            </textField>
                            <br>


                            <g:message code="Last Name"/>

                             <textField class="field" name="lastName"  id="Company">
                              <label for="txt4"></label>
                              <input type="text" name="txt4" id="txt4" value="${contact.lastName}">
                            </textField>

                            <br>

                            <g:message code="Title"/>

                             <textField class="field" name="title"  id="Company">
                              <label for="txt5"></label>
                              <input type="text" name="txt5" id="txt5" value="${contact.title}">
                            </textField>

                          </content>
                       </content>     
          </div>
         </div> 
        </fieldset>
       </form> 
     </div>
   </div>
 </content>
```

When executed,it is showing

Grails tag [g:applyLayout] was not closed

I have rechecked it many times.But my tag is properly closed.What should i do to render this template properly?I also tried converting this template to a view.But same error.I have this applyLayout working properly in another template.I have copied it from there.Don't know why it is not working here.
EDIT:Full gsp code which is working:
**list.gsp**//view that renders other templates

```
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="panels" />

</head>
<body>

 %{--show all user's details--}%
 <sec:ifAllGranted roles="MENU_90">
 <content tag="column1">
    <g:render template="customers" model="[users: users,results:results]"/>
 </content>


 </sec:ifAllGranted>

</body>
</html>
```

**_Customers.gsp**//template in which applyLayout is working fine

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function asd(tdcId, companyId, companyType,companyName) {
 alert(companyName);
 var link = "${g.createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'showcontacts')}?tdc=" + tdcId + "&companyid=" + companyId + "&companytype=" + companyType+ "&companyname=" + companyName;
   window.open(link, '', 'width=200,height=100');
}

</script>

<div class="form-edit">
    <div class="heading">
        <strong>
            <g:message code="Firm Profile"/>
        </strong>
    </div>

    <div id="hai" class="form-hold">
        <g:form name="company-edit-form" action="save">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-columns">


                    <div class="column">
                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Company Name"/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Company</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Company"  id="Company"  />
                        </g:applyLayout>
                         <g:applyLayout name="form/checkbox">
                             <content tag="label"><g:message code="Starts with"/</content>
                             <content tag="label.for">Starts with</content>
                             <g:checkBox class="cb checkbox" name="StartsWith" />
                        </g:applyLayout>
                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Street"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Street</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Street" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                         <g:applyLayout name="form/checkbox">
                             <content tag="label"><g:message code="Starts with"/</content>
                             <content tag="label.for">Starts With</content>
                             <g:checkBox class="cb checkbox" name="StreetStartsWith"/>
                        </g:applyLayout>
                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Zip code"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Zip</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="ZipCode"/>
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Fagrubrik"/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Fagrubrik</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Fagrubrik" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="House no."/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">HouseNo</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="HouseNo" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Tel./Fax."/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Telephone</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Telephone" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Company No."/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">CompanyNo</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="CompanyNo" />
                        </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="City"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">City</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="City" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                        <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="TDC ID"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">TdcId</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="TdcId" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Industry Designation"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Industry Designation</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="IndustryDesignation" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Decision Maker"/</content>
                            <content tag="label.for">DecisionMaker</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="DecisionMaker" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="Email"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">Email</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="Email" />
                             </g:applyLayout>

                             <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                            <content tag="label"><g:message code="WWW"/></content>
                            <content tag="label.for">WWW</content>
                            <g:textField class="field" name="WWW"/>
                             </g:applyLayout>


                    </div>

                </div>


                <div>
                    <br/>&nbsp;
                </div>



            </fieldset>
            <div id="button" class="buttons">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <g:submitButton  id="button" class="buttons" name="Search" value="Search" action="search" style= "background-color:#191DD4 text-color:#FFFFFF"/>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

        </g:form>
           <div class="table-box">
           <g:if test="${company}">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small"><g:message code="Company Name"/></th>
        <th class="medium"><g:message code="TDCID"/></th>
        <th class="tiny"><g:message code="STREET"/></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <g:each in="${company}" status="idx" var="PNo">

       <tr>
         <td>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:asd('${PNo.tdcId}', '${PNo.companyId}', '${PNo.companyType}', '${PNo.officialName}');">${PNo.officialName}</a>


         </td>
         <td>
         <g:remoteLink action="show" id="${PNo}" before="register(this);" 
                       onSuccess="render(data, next);" params="[template:'show']">
             ${PNo.tdcId}
         </g:remoteLink>
         </td>
         <td>

              ${PNo.street}

         </td>
       </tr>

        </g:each>
     </tbody>
  </table>     
</g:if>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is referring to this one? If you are using `applyLayout` elsewhere make sure they are close as well.

Comment: yes iam sure about it because the filename and line number are also shown along with the error

Comment: Change the `name` in `<g:applyLayout name="form/input">` to something else (without a `/`) in the name and see how it behaves.

Comment: Is it an exception? Can you show us the entire stacktrace?

Comment: i tried avoiding / in the name but still the error persists.Also it is working fine with / in the name in another template.:stacktrace:
ERROR [StackTrace] Sanitizing stacktrace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Grails tag [g:applyLayout] was not closed at E:\office\Softwares\jbilling tools\src\grails-app\views\customer\_showcontacts.gsp:38
 at CustomerController$_closure11.doCall(CustomerController.groovy:461)
 at CustomerController$_closure11.doCall(CustomerController.groovy)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Can you post your gsp code with which this template is working. And make sure that your all content tag close in which you implement this template.

Answer (score 0):

I am not html expert , I just made amendment and it work for me.

```
<div class="form-edit">
<div class="heading">
    <strong>
        <g:message code="Contact Details of the firm:"/>${name}
    </strong>
</div>

<div id="hai" class="form-hold">
    <form name="company-edit-form" action="save">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-columns">

                <div class="column">
                    <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
                        <content tag="label"><g:message code="Company Name"/></content>
                        <content tag="label.for">Company</content>
                        <g:textField class="field" name="Company" id="Company"/>
                    </g:applyLayout>
                    <content tag="label"><g:message code="First Name"/>

                        <textField class="field" name="firstName" id="Company">
                            <label for="txt1"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" value="${contact?.firstName}">
                        </textField>
                        <br>

                        <g:message code="Group"/>

                        <textField class="field" name="group" id="Company">
                            <label for="txt2"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" value="${contact?.group}">
                        </textField>

                        <br>

                        <g:message code="ID"/>

                        <textField class="field" name="id" id="Company">
                            <label for="txt3"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="txt3" id="txt3" value="${contact?.id}">
                        </textField>
                        <br>


                        <g:message code="Last Name"/>

                        <textField class="field" name="lastName" id="Company">
                            <label for="txt4"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="txt4" id="txt4" value="${contact?.lastName}">
                        </textField>

                        <br>

                        <g:message code="Title"/>

                        <textField class="field" name="title" id="Company">
                            <label for="txt5"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="txt5" id="txt5" value="${contact?.title}">
                        </textField>

                    </content>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is with value="${contact.firstName}" not being written like value="${contact?.firstName}" ?